# How to get time in format: 2014-12-19 22:48:44 in Ruby on Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am using Time.zone.now to spit out a timestamp in Ruby on Rails 4.  However, this is spitting out the time in the format:

```
2014-12-19 22:48:44 UTC
```

When I just want:

```
2014-12-19 22:48:44
```

Is there anyway to do this in Ruby on Rails 4?  Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, Ruby has a method called `#strftime` which accepts a format mask and will return a string in the requested format. [Ruby Docs](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Time.html#method-i-strftime)

You would want:

```
'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
```

However, I recommend using the Rails i18n functionality. You should read the [docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#adding-date-time-formats) to get the whole story. In a nutshell, if your locale was called `en` then you could add a file at `config/locales/localization.en.yml` and put the following content in it:

```
# config/locales/localization.en.yml
en:
  time:
    formats:
      default: ! '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
```

Then, wherever you output a timestamp you could write the following ERB (note `l` it is a method name):

```
<%= l some_timestamp %>
```

And the output will be in that default format. If you don't want that format to be the default then give it another name in the YAML file:

```
# config/locales/localization.en.yml
en:
  time:
    formats:
      no_tz: '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
```

And then the ERB would become:

```
<%= l some_timestamp, format: :no_tz %>
```

Since most applications output more than one timestamp or date, this will keep all your formats in one place.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [`strftime`](http://apidock.com/ruby/v1_9_3_125/Time/strftime).

I am 100% sure you'll find what you are looking for.

## EDIT

According to info appeared in comments, I recommend to change `Time.zone.now` to `DateTime.now`, since the aim is to write to DB column of a `datetime` type

Comment: I am actually not looking for a string, I am still looking for a datetime (that is what the column is going to be populated as).  However, I am getting an error with the UTC included.  In tutorials I've read, Time.zone.now should do the job, but for some reason it is not.  The error I'm getting is: "Mysql2::Error: Incorrect datetime value:"  Any ideas?

Comment: @user1072337 Yes, the format for `datetime` column should be `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss`, probably because of this `UTC` you're getting the error. I recommend to not working around with Time with zones, but just use `DateTime.now` when it comes to writing to DB column of `datetime` type